# Add the innerHTML of a div within erb

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a link that takes an id of a user. This is kept in a div called NameID. The controller etc is all set up correctly but all I need to do is to be able to pass the NameID.innerHTML (which is a number) as the number that people.id represents. How can I do this?

`index.html.erb` (graph not shown)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="BtnMessageNode" href="/messages/new">Start conversation</a></p>

                <h2>NameID of Node</h2>
                <div id="NameID_Div"></div>

          </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<% page_header "Users" %>


<ul>
  <% @peoples.each do |people| %>
    <li>
      <strong><%= people.name %></strong>
      <% unless current_user == people %>
        <%= link_to 'Send message', new_message_path(to: people.id), class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @chosen_recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]
  end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end
end
```

Comment: please paste your complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to embed your `NameID.innerHTML` into ERB. So I would suggest using some custom jQuery instead. First, add an id to your link:

```
<%= link_to 'Send message', new_message_path(to: people.id), id: 'sendMessage', class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>
```

Then use jQuery inside your script:

```
$("#sendMessage").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var nameId = $("#NameID_Div").html();
  // Then just assign the proper URL of the new_message_path with the proper NameID
  location.assign('/message/' + nameId + '/new');
});
```

Comment: Hi Abraar. The code doesnt work. I think the sendmessage output needs to be instead of the people.id. The people.id is only defined as part of a loop from the @peoples variable from the controller. If I can put the jquery result into here then I wont need to use the people variable at all. How can I put the jquery output so that its passed as part of the to: parameter?